# how to apply to avoid adding all .test classes from the page in the code $( ".test" ).insertBefore( ".test1" )

Tags: jquery

how to apply to avoid adding all .test classes from the page in the code

$( ".test" ).insertBefore( ".test1" )

```
<div id="testdiv">
<div class="test1"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

div is replicated on the page

Comment: modify your selector to target only required element

Comment: unfortunately I have just one selector for whole page

Comment: can not help without looking at html

Comment: <div id="test-div><div class="test1"></div><div class="test"></div></div> which is replicated a new time on the page

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over each test element and insert it before its previous sibling `.test`:

```
$(".test").each(function(){
  $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
}) ;
```